# How can I change UINavigationBar per view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change the color of the UINavigationBar, per the view controller in my stack of view controllers. As in, a way that I can tell a view controller to seque and then change the navigation bar color. The only issue is when I try to seque; the navigation color stays the same from the previous view controller. My code in my first VC's viewDidLoad is:

```
if let navController = self.navigationController {
        navController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        navController.navigationBar.translucent = false 
        navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()]
}
```

Then in my next VC I want to inver that to be

```
if let navController = self.navigationController {
        navController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()]        
}
```

I tried to invert it on the viewDidDissapear; but that just looked glitchy. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested your code and it is working fine for me here is my code:

**FirstViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let navController = self.navigationController {
            navController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
            navController.navigationBar.translucent = false
            navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()]
        }
    }
    //Add this code if you want same color for when you come back to your first viewController
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        if let navController = self.navigationController {
            navController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
            navController.navigationBar.translucent = false
            navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()]
        }
    }
}
```

**SecondViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class SViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let navController = self.navigationController {
            navController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()]

        }
    }
}
```

And [HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=04736065553693866204) is sample project.

Answer (score 1):

Customize your view controllers' navigation bars in the **-viewWillAppear** method of each view controller!

This will prevent any glitchy appearance, like you mentioned -viewDidDisappear did, because it will be called right before each view controller loads (before the user sees the loaded views).