# Navigation Bar Transparency

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3

Could Anybody help me with that, I have found this code here in this website, That code helps me to transparent the navigation bar:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

The problem is how could I get the default navigation bar?
I have two ViewController The first I want it with normal navigation bar and the second with transparent navigation bar, and when I get back to the first I need to get default navigation bar back :).

Comment: [Did you look at this one?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31752215/4029561)

Comment: yes, I want to get it back its default appearance, white blurred view, when I use the code like this it is only being white but it's not blurred  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, In the second view I used this code:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

,And in first view this code:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: ""), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Thank you all for your help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I was working on an app which needed 3 navigation styles transparent, translucent and default. After all the investigation and tests finally I had to create a custom navigation bar. I have wasted almost a week to finally use this approach.